# Returning value from event

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events, puppeteer

I am creating a little project with node and puppeteer but that doesn't matter.

What matter is that I want to return a value from a function (code block below is an async function).
The first event always occurs before the second one I and want to return the first two values emitted by those events

```
  client.on('Network.webSocketCreated', ({ url }) => {
    const serverUrl = url
  })

  client.once('Network.webSocketFrameSent', ({ response }) => {
    const credentials = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.payloadData)[0])
    return [credentials, serverUrl]
  })
```

With this implementation I get undefined, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is fast and draft way

```
  // Set it in parent scope
  let serverUrl;
  
  // This event firs
  client.on('Network.webSocketCreated', ({ url }) => {
    // Assign
    serverUrl = url
  })

  client.once('Network.webSocketFrameSent', ({ response }) => {
    const credentials = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.payloadData)[0])
    // Use
    return [credentials, serverUrl]
  })
```

But keep in mind, that now you trying to return value inside event function. This isn't what you want I think. Instead you can call some function with these two parameters passed as arguments: `myFunction(credentials, serverUrl);`

Comment: I want to return result of main function as firsts outputs of this two events to be precise

Comment: there is not enough information in your example about what you are doing, where is main function etc...